# Which GCP product should I use to implement a microservice?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, microservices, serverless

I'm building a microservice to manage print jobs using node. It's a small restful api that will be polled by printers thousands of times per day.

For this to scale well, which product from GCP will work well? I'm also using firebase, so cloud functions would be easy but I'm not sure if there's a better option.

Comment: There is too few information about your microservice. Request max duration? CPU usage? Number of route in the API? Is there some third party binary/library to install?

Comment: It's a printing microservice. Dozens of printers polling every 5 seconds. Routing is very simple. Max duration, I'm guessing but no more than 4000 ms? Enough time to query a queue table of print jobs and render the receipt content.

Comment: You have to focus on the API. If you have several paths (at least 3), code base that you want to use in each path (authentication, printer ID,...) or you don't want to write your API in node, Cloud Function is not the most relevant product (IMO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Function will be my best guess, coupled with Cloud Pub/Sub Triggers to be more efficient. You will be able to add Cloud Logging if that is something that may interest you.

https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub